# Python 3.4 open(file, 'a') aifc.Error

Tags: io, mode, python-3.4

[I'm using Netbeans](https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/python_in_netbeans_ide_8) to write python, and I had it so that I could append a file (in Eclipse) with `file = open('dir\file', 'a')` so I could append a file, but I get this:

```
aifc.Error: mode must be 'r', 'rb', 'w', or 'wb'
```

I don't want to have to read the file, save either to array or temp file and then rewrite. What's going on?

Note: I get the same thing in Command Prompt, which seems weird to me.

Also, I know my interpreter is configured properly and everything is in the python34 folder (namely `python34\Lib\site-packages`)

Full error message on run:

```
Running...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Prog\PythonCurrent\RadioDB\src\radiodb.py", line 122, in <module>
    main()
  File "G:\Prog\PythonCurrent\RadioDB\src\radiodb.py", line 43, in main
    lineTypesFile = open('{}/Desktop/GPS Line Types.txt'.format(home), 'a')
  File "c:\Python34\lib\aifc.py", line 891, in open
    raise Error("mode must be 'r', 'rb', 'w', or 'wb'")
aifc.Error: mode must be 'r', 'rb', 'w', or 'wb'
```

Comment: Where is this error showing up? When you actually run the script or in the source code itself via Netbeans syntax checking?

Comment: When I run the script. It doesn't show up beforehand.

Comment: @dano **a** option is out of possible options ????

Comment: Figured it out: Netbeans automatically configured my imports; because it didn't see where the `open()` function was coming from, it imported the first instance of a method named `open()` and imported it (from aifc module in this case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error is coming from the [`aifc`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/aifc.html) module. [`aifc.open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/aifc.html#aifc.open) only supports the `r`, `rb`, `w`, and `wb` modes. Are you calling `from aifc import *` somewhere in your script? If so, don't do that! It's shadowing the built-in `open` with `aifc.open`. Only import the functions you need from `aifc`.

Comment: Nope. Shouldn't it just import itself since it's built in (or so I thought)?

Comment: Indeed it is/should be imported because it can tell me what file the error is coming from (and this worked in Eclipse, so aifc should know 'a' for second param is!!!!)

Comment: @Dylan Well, it really doesn't make any sense for the `open` from `aifc` to be in your module's namespace then. The only think I can think of is you configured the path for the interpreter wrong. Does the error go away if you use python34\Lib instead of python34\Lib\site-packages?

Comment: I figured it out... Netbeans auto-imported for me. I had `from aifc import open` and I guess that overrode the built-in feature `open()`. That's a bit annoying.

Comment: @Dylan Netbeans didn't auto-import it, you manually imported it with the call to `from aifc import open`. That will make the `open` from `aifc` part of the global namespace of your module, and shadow the built-in open. Either just use `import aifc` and use `aifc.open` or use `__builtins__.open` to access the built-in `open` function.

Comment: interp is set to C:\python34\python.exe` on windows. As i said, Netbeans found the first instance of `open(param1, param2)` and imported it. And it was auto-imported because when you press ctrl + shft + i, Netbeans configures your imports and imports what you need (or really just don't have in python).

Comment: No... Ctrl + Shft + i in netbeans = auto import + import reformat